# How to use Async Await inside template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, material-ui, mui-autocomplete

The below code just returns string literal. I read somewhere that Async-Await inside template string needs to have top-level await but how can I get top-level await in my case?

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import usePlacesAutocomplete, {getGeocode, getZipCode} from "use-places-autocomplete";


const Places = () => { 
<Autocomplete        
   renderOption={(props, option) => 
     <li {...props}> 
        {`${ async () => await getGeocode({placeId: option.place_id})
                                .then(results => getZipCode(results[0], true))()}
        `}
        </li> }
      />
}
```

Comment: You need to await the value before the render of the list item. Even then `renderOption` may not work with promises. This looks like react? If so, consider fetching the geocode first, updating the state, and then passing that to the render.

Comment: Inside a function is by definition **not** at the top level. Even outside that arrow function appears to be inside a React component, so still not at the top level.

Comment: Your `async` wrapper makes no sense, adding it to the code from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77449970/2) achieves nothing. Start over without it.

Comment: It seems you are using react? What is `<Autocomplete>`? Did you contact its documentation to how (or whether) it supports asynchronous requests?

Comment: "*I read somewhere that Async-Await inside template string needs to have top-level await*" - where did you read that? It's nonsense. Also, why are you using a template literal at all?

Comment: @Bergi I am using template literal because I want to return a value from the given code. getZipcode returns a promise object with the zipCode inside it but I am not able to retrieve the zipcode. That is why I tried async await which I belive is not the right way of doing it.

Comment: @Pasang A template literal does not help with returning a value. If `getZipCode` were to return the value that you want (instead of a promise), you wouldn't need to wrap that in a template literal to use it. But again, you need to tell us more about `AutoComplete` if you need our help with solving this.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the quick response. AutoComplete is a component from Material UI which works as a dropdown that gives a list of zipcodes as per what I have typed. I have used 'use-places-autocomplete' library which has 'getZipCode' that returns a Promise object and I can see the zipCode inside the promise object but am not able to retrieve it.

Comment: In that case, did you read https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests?

Answer (score -2):

I think You should extract the async request from the string literal

May Be Create a new Component called Option which takes args needed for api calls as Props and do the api call inside useEffect